# A div with min-width in a column, Bootstrap 3.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two **Bootstrap** columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><div class="my"></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">some text</div>
</div>
```

They are both half a grid due to `col-md-6`. Now, I need set up the minimal width of `div.my`. If I apply `min-width`, I have a side-effect: when minimizing, at one point the `div.my` overlaps the parent column (before both columns are 100% width).

I have no intention to set up minimal width of the column itself, because `div.my` could have margins.

I know, I can use media-queries, but is there a better solution?

Regards,

Comment: Percentage width is no problem but is with fixed pixels.

Comment: Note: you're missing a `</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly use media queries, what reason is there not to?

They will give you complete control of how things look at any given size.

To prevent the overlapping div causing problems you could use.

```
.col-md-6 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It would be better to use a different class though, `.col-md-6.no-overflow` for example.

It's difficult to give a conclusive answer without knowing the content and purpose of the `.my` div.

Comment: Why, .col-md-6 { width: 100%; } is better. Also, I've been told LESS vars are even better. Too bad I'm not using LESS yet. Anyway, the media query is the solution I've ended with.

Comment: Oh, I've got it wrong. I mean, I use a media-query with `.col-md-6 { width: 100%; }`. Disabling overflow is bad anyway, because the content is cropped.

Comment: It is bad to crop the div, but if it is overflowing and you want a min-width, without making it smaller, what choice do you have?

Comment: Having read your question again, you need to alter the breakpoint value, or add a new breakpoint that sets the col to 100% sooner.

Answer (score 1):

you could have use `calc()` feature of css for `width`, `min-width` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-width:300px !important;"><div class="my"></div>
                </div>    
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

`min-width` property is used to set the minimal `width` that that div will have in any case so it will not go below this width. You have to use `max-width` for that so:

```
div.my
{
max-width: 80%
}
```

For responsiveness its always good to use %